# How can I import library in IronPython?

Tags: c#, python, import, ironpython, music21

I'm currently working on an application written in C#, which I'm embedding `IronPython` in.

I want to import library [music21](http://mit.edu/music21/)
This library is working normally on `PyScripter`, but on `IronPython` is not. I tried with

```
import sys
sys.path.append(r"c:\python24\lib")
```

but it did't worked.

I tried even with copying `music21` lib folder into the lib of `IronPython` and type in `IronPython` console:

```
from music import *
```

I get next error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "(stdin)", line 1, in (module)
File "C:\ProgramFiles\IronPython 2.7\Lib\music21\__init__.py", line 123, in (module)
KeyError: abc
```

What should I do?

Comment: If it helps anyone, "abc" is the first submodule imported by music21, so probably the original music21.__init__ file is being found properly, but the path hasn't actually been set for music21 to find its submodules.  (I don't use IronPython, so I can't help from there)

Comment: because of this potential conflict, the "abc" module in music21 is now called "abcFormat"